# asp.net url value causes error

Tags: asp.net, validation, query-string

I have a string parameter I pass around using the querystring, I'll call it: Request.QueryString["x"]. If i manually enter a URL like: mypage.aspx?x=co%3Csub%3E2, asp.net doesn't have the chance to get its hands on the value before throwing an error. Is there a way to safely allow this value to be pulled down and validated using my own logic WITHOUT turning validateinput off?

The problem is that we have custom error pages which send me an e-mail when they're hit. Bots pummel our site, and on occasion, I'll come into work and have 500 e-mails from errors like this waiting in my inbox. I'd like to do my own validation and display my own error message on the page they're trying to access.

Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing in asp.net that will cause an error just by calling that url. Perhaps you have an http module or code in  global.asax that is doing work when the request is made? What error do you get?

Comment: On another note: error pages should be plain HTML files, not managed .NET pages; handle errors using the applications `OnError` event handler.

Comment: Craig, the error is: A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client (x="co<sub>2"). Maybe there is a way to manage URL input through some other means? This error happens very early, before a single line of page code is touched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do that without **turning validateinput off**. Could you encode your querystring somehow so that ASP will validate it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe its not possible without validateinput off. Maybe you can change you custom 500 page to not e-mail exeptions of this type